# ruby on rails chapter 8, 3rd Edition. About menu dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to show the about dropdown menu when signed in to the user account. I am not using heroko, running it in my local server, but I dont think that should make a difference.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

and my session controller

class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
     user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you made the change mentioned in [Listing 8.17](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-bootstrap_js) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `logged_in?` method declared? They is responsible for the login status of the user.