# Hartl 3rd ed section 8.2.3 dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I click on the "Account" link in the navbar, the dropdown menu does not appear. What does happen is a # is added to the end of the URL, so users/1 becomes users/1#.

A question about the dropdown not working has been asked here: [ruby on rails chapter 8, 3rd Edition. About menu dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261764/ruby-on-rails-chapter-8-3rd-edition-about-menu-dropdown). I have tried a number of variations with my application.js file, as I will show below, and as far as I know, my sessions_controller.rb and my sessions_helper.rb match what Hartl has.

I am using Windows and Chrome.

I have enabled "show user agent shadow DOM" in the dev console in Chrome and I see the html for the dropdown menu. I don't see any error messages.

I think there is either a controller error or a Bootstrap/Sass/Rails version incompatibility of some kind. I did get the dropdown to work in Hartl 2nd ed chapter 8, but I don't want to roll my gems back that far.

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I've also tried

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And I've tried subbing bootstrap-sprockets for bootstrap.

sessions_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

I tried replacing !current_user.nil? with current_user.nil? but that didn't work.

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Gemfile (portion)

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
```

Custom.css.scss (first 2 lines)

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

And finally, _header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Birder's Life List App", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",   help_path %></li>
          <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
I found this post: http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/

and I ran

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

Then I checked my application.js file and found that I had somehow changed

```
//= require bootstrap
```

to

```
//= bootstrap
```

I know I had this correct when I was having problems before, so I don't think this was the reason for the dropdown problem.

The RailsGuide on the Asset Pipeline mentions rake assets:precompile in the production environment. I have not been able to get

```
bin/rake assets:precompile
```

to work.